# Use a space in a flag value in a Golang directive

Tags: go, go-flag

How do you get spaces in flag values when using directives?

#### Context

The `flag` package receives and/or handles flags with spaces differently depending on how Go is called. Quoting the flag *value* works from the command-line but not with a directive, such as `go generate`, for example.

In other words, called from the command line, `Flag1` will receive the correct value (i.e., 4 words, 3 spaces).

#### Works

```
% go run -tags generate main.go -Flag1="flag value with spaces"
```

#### Doesn't Work

However, calling the exact same command in a directive file, e.g., with `go generate ./...`, `Flag1` will not receive the correct value. Take a directive file (e.g., `generate.go`) with this line in it:

```golang
//go:generate go run -tags generate main.go -Flag1="flag value with spaces" -Flag2=next
```

`Flag1` is not set correctly and `Flag2` is not set at all.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments to `go run` are parsed by your shell.  The go:generate directive does its own parsing and that parsing is different from shells.

The relevant [go:generate documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Generate_Go_files_by_processing_source) is:

> The arguments to the directive are space-separated tokens or double-quoted strings passed to the generator as individual arguments when it is run.

> Quoted strings use Go syntax and are evaluated before execution; a quoted string appears as a single argument to the generator.

Each argument is separated by spaces. An argument is either a "token" or a double-quoted string. The documentation does not describe a token, but we can assume it means a sequence of non-space characters.

Quoted strings are evaluated.  That means that quotes are removed, escape sequences are unescaped, etc.  The implementation evaluates the string using [strconv.Unquote](https://pkg.go.dev/strconv#Unquote).

Based on the above, use:

```
//go:generate go run -tags generate main.go "-Flag1=flag value with spaces"
```

The important change here is the `"` is moved forward to a position where it's proceeded by a space.  Quotes inside of a token are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Extrapolating from [an old, related, but not the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32468283/2121526), enclose the entire flag key, dash, and value in quotes.

```golang
//go:generate go run -tags generate main.go "-Flag1=flag value with spaces"
```

This syntax has the advantage of working on the command line or in directive files.

None of the current documentation (that I could find) provides a clear answer:

- The [`flag` documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#hdr-Command_line_flag_syntax) does not mention flag values with spaces.
- The [directive documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Generate_Go_files_by_processing_source) provides this cryptic hint that leads you to the correct solution (though a bit more clarity would be helpful).

> Quoted strings use Go syntax and are evaluated before execution; a quoted string appears as a single argument to the generator.

Comment: When entered through the shell command line, the arguments to a process will be passed to the process *after* the shell processes them. That's why in the first case the quotes are removed, but with go:generate, the subprocess receives the argument quoted.

Comment: Also note that while the `go` tools make some exceptions for misuse, you generally should not be adding flags after the positional arguments since it's not universally accepted (with the `flags` package here being the most obvious example)